# invoking WinApi when using long path

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, createfile

Can anyone help me please?

I tried to `P/Invoke` the WINAPI method from managed .net code.
`CreateFile()` method is always returning false. If I make the given path less than 256 it just works fine but not if greater than 256. I might be doing something wrong .
According to this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2008/07/07/long-paths-in-net-part-3-of-3-redux-kim-hamilton.aspx) I should be able to use long path file that is greater than 256 in length.

Below is the code that I tried:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string path =            @"c:\tttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttttttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaatttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttttttttttaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttttt";

        LongPath.TestCreateAndWrite(path);

        }


    // This code snippet is provided under the Microsoft Permissive License.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
    EFileShare dwShareMode,
    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
    ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
    EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile);




public static void TestCreateAndWrite(string fileName) {

    string formattedName = @"\\?\" + fileName;
    //string formattedName = @"\\?\UNC" + fileName;
    // Create a file with generic write access
    SafeFileHandle fileHandle = CreateFile(formattedName, EFileAccess.GenericWrite, 
       EFileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero,  ECreationDisposition.CreateAlways, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    // Check for errors
    int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (fileHandle.IsInvalid) {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(lastWin32Error);
    }

    // Pass the file handle to FileStream. FileStream will close the
    // handle
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileHandle,
                                    FileAccess.Write)) {
        fs.WriteByte(80);
        fs.WriteByte(81);
        fs.WriteByte(83);
        fs.WriteByte(84);
    }
}
```

This method throws error code 3 which is file path not specified according to System Error Codes (0-499) (Windows).

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: In this specific code sample you are trying to use a path component that is longer than 256 characters; NTFS has a limit of 256 (or maybe it is 255, I forget) characters per path component.  The "\\?\" prefix helps for paths that are longer than 256 characters, but the individual path components are still limited to 255 or 256 characters.  Basically a folder or file name cannot be longer than 255 or 256 characters.

Answer (score 3):

While the `\\?\` notation allows you to use paths whose total length is longer than `MAX_PATH`, you still have to respect the per-component limit reported by `GetVolumeInformation`. For NTFS, the per-component limit is 255, which means you are not allowed to go more than 255 characters without a backslash.